# Azure Function running from Docker Container has different files inside

Tags: c#, azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-function-app

As seen on the image below, the local docker container's contents do not match the one pushed to Azure Function App. I am exploring the azure function app with Kudu and I am using docker run to interact with the local container.

This is an issue, as I have an external library that I import with `DllImport`, so the code can never find the actual library file no matter where I put it.

What causes this and what is the solution?

This is the last layer of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:2.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
COPY --from=compile_engine ["/app/tmp/src/libml_inference_engine.so", "/azure-functions-host"]
COPY --from=compile_engine ["/app/tmp/src/libml_inference_engine.so", "/bin"]
COPY --from=compile_engine ["/app/tmp/src/libml_inference_engine.so", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the function app from a custom docker image, the path `/home/site/wwwroot` inside the container is not the same as the path `/home/site/wwwroot` in the kudu. There are two different containers between kudu and the container from your custom image. So you cannot see the same things on both the same paths.

The solution is that you can set the environment variable `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true`. Then the function will use the path `/home/site/wwwroot` cover the same path inside the custom container. So you will see the same things in both where. It also shows all the things of that path in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Why does kudu see something different in that path? Does it simply ignore the files or does it create its own container?

Comment: I tried setting WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE to true, now wwwroot contains "host.json", but none of the original dlls that I expected to be there like in the docker image.
Also, the functions are now gone.

Comment: @EduardG As I said in the answer, kudu is a different container from your custom image container. And when you set the environment variable WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE as true, then the kudu path `/home/site/wwwroot` will  cover the same path in your custom image container.

Comment: As there are no other answers and yours shines some light on the topic, I have accepted it as the answer. I am still confused as to why after enabling that config setting, the local docker image does not match the one uploaded to Azure, since from your comment I understand that if that is set to true then it should.

Comment: @EduardG You need to understand the meaning. The path in Kudu will cover the path in your custom image container. So you need to upload the files into the path in kudu. Then you can see the files inside your custom image container.

Comment: I was chasing red herrings. Part of my question was why DllImport wasn't finding the files I put in there and I thought you meant that Kudu replaced those files somehow, but in fact it was finding it, but I had compiled it incorrectly. For anyone reading this - in my case, the app was in /home/site/wwwroot/bin and the azure function host was in /azure-functions-host/something.dll, the DllImport was looking at the bin folder, but once you run a function it will start in the root "/" as a work directory. DllImport will fail saying it can't find the file if its compiled for the wrong architecture

Comment: @EduardG I know your app is in the path /home/site/wwwroot of the container. How do you understand what I said in the answer?

Comment: I think we diverged somewhere since you advised me to upload files into the path in kudu, and I ultimately just added them to the docker image.